# Drawing with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to use the Tkinter library to draw some simple shapes? Say I display an image of a map for example, could I let the user place start and stop points on the map, and have the distance between the the point show up in an Entry() box?

ThankS!

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter ?

Comment: if you'r researching, i recommend using other libraries for that (pygame,qt,gtk)

Comment: @ali: why? tkinter is perfectly fine for drawing simple objects on the screen. It's OK to have a preference, but redirecting someone to another tool or library without an explanation isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tkinter has a `Canvas` widget that lets you draw lines, polygons, ovals, text, as well as images.

Here's a simple example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # draw some items
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,50,150,150, fill="red")
        self.canvas.create_oval(20,20,65, 75, outline="green")
        self.canvas.create_text(10,200, anchor="nw", text="Hello, world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

A nice tutorial can be found here: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html